# text show when hover img1 - hide only when hover img2

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Have something like:

```
<div id="Oobj51">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function() {
            $('#Oobj51').hover(function() {
                $("#Oobj58").show(500);
            }), 
            $("#Oobj58").hover(function() {
                //do nothing if hovered over
            }, 
            function(){
                //hide on hover out
                $("#Oobj58").hide(500);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'"                            onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>
</div>
```

Then I have 7 images like "Oobj51" and to each one of them there's a part of form in this case "Oobj58". 
How to make the Oobj58 disaapear not when hover out but when hover on next img "Oobj52" where next part of form "Oobj59" should appear.??

Comment: Are you trying to show complementary images along a large list of images? I mean, when you hover Oobj51 Oobj58 shows up, when you hover Oobj52 then Oobj59 shows up and every other image is hidden and so on...?

Comment: excatly. the code below works already. Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give every div the same class name:

```
<div class="Oobj" id="Oobj51">
```

Then use the id of the hovered div to define what to do next:

```
$(function() {
   $('.Oobj').hover(function() {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        if(currentId == 'Oobj51') {
            $("#Oobj58").show();
            $("#Oobj59").hide();
        } else if(currentId == 'Oobj52') {
            $("#Oobj58").hide();
            $("#Oobj59").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: works perfectly! thanks. 
any idea how to make background img stay as onmouseover when hover out but form still active?

Comment: Do you mean with active when an input has focus? In that case I would use hover on the div only to show the form and blur on the input to hide the form: `$('input').blur(function() { $(this).closest('.form').hide(); });` Or something like that.

Comment: But you'd write a new css with hover or do you mean to use the previous java code you've wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at mouseenter event (doc http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```
$("#Oobj51").mouseenter(function() 
{
  $("#Oobj58").show();
})
$("#Oobj51").mouseleave(function() 
{
  $("#Oobj58").hide();
});
```